# Step-by-step usage of Visual Studio Git Extension for merging

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2013, merge

Every group project I work on in Visual Studio using it's Git Extension plugin, we run into problems merging. Strange or unexpected merge conflicts occur for specific cases, and I don't know where we're going wrong or how our interpretation of how to use git is askew.

Our setup is this. There is a master branch, where all the finalized code goes, and each developer has their own local work branch. The developers code in their branch, and when ready, after having been code reviewed by others and agreed upon by the entire team, they can merge to the master branch.

To test the functionality of the master branch, we each added an empty class with a separate name to our local work branch, then committed. After committing, one by one we were going to merge into master. I merged, and everything worked fine. Then another developer attempted to merge their local branch with master and received a merge error.

The merge error occurred in the .csproj file. It was trying to override the class I added (which was named "Michael.cs") with the file that the other developer added (which was named "Roman.cs"). The following picture illustrates the merge conflict:

[image]

Note that before we each added our own class, we were all synchronized. After we added our classes and committed to our local branches, we did not synchronize again.

This type of merge conflict occurs a lot, and it's very irritating. So, I would like to know, once and for all, what **exactly**, down to every mouse click, is the process for merging in Visual Studio + Git so that errors like these don't occur. What is the step-by-step, guaranteed to work process that will ensure these merge conflicts never occur.

Don't bother linking to documentation. I've already read it, and it's not of use to us.

Comment: Oh, the joy of merging .csproj files (or XML files in general). Wait until both of you update the same or a different NuGet package, or an EDMX.

Comment: The exact process is: deal with having merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Though this isn't a step by step procedure for merging in VS, this will help. **Make sure in your `.gitattributes` file you have the line `*.csproj merge=union` (and possibly the same for `*.sln` and whatever other VS project or related files you need)**. This will resolve simple merge conflicts automatically, like the example in the original question, but some larger conflicts can still occur (though more rarely).